# OpenCV persist with ODB

Tags: c++, opencv, persist, odb

Hello I'm trying to persist a class in c++ using ODB. However when I compile the .h using the odb compiler, it crashes showing the following error:

```
error: unable to map C++ type '::cv::Mat' used in data member 'data' to a MySQL database type
Class.h:24:13: info: use '#pragma db type' to specify the database type
```

Does any way to map it easily exist?

Thank you

Comment: i kinda doubt if it is possible *at all*